# How to redirect One control to another view in Mvc3  Jquery Mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

i have develop a Mvc3 application in that i have integrating Jquerymobile,when try to login the page Both devices are working but after login there is one Button for redirect to another view page.When i click that button in Desktop device is working fine but i mobile device it showing error like "Error in pageloding"
  Here is my Controle page code

```
       [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Login(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl, FormCollection collection)
    {
        var silButton = Request.Params.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(key => key.StartsWith("Button_"));
        string name = silButton;

        if (silButton == "Button_login")
        {
            try
            {
                string uname = model.UserName;
                string pwd = model.Password;
                bool id = model.RememberMe;
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                        {
                            return Redirect(returnUrl);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index","DashBoard");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }

        }
        else
        {
           //Here i want page redirect but it showing error ;
           return RedirectToActionPermanent("FacebookLogin", "IlifelooksShare");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add some of the code you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you dont have forms authentication setup properly in your web.config - the desktop lets this continue but on iphone etc it doesnt work - try commenting out the call to validateuser and replace with if(true) and you should see it all work (without obviously validating who the user is!)